# como obter resposta de else ao digitar uma string python

Tags: python

```
num = int(input('Digite um número: '))

if num % 2 == 0:
    print('O valor é par')

elif num % 2 != 0:
    print('O valor é ímpar')

else:
    print('Dado inválido')
```

Mas se eu digito uma string por exemplo, aparece esse erro:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '#'
```

Como fazer que ao digitar a string caia na condição else?

Comment: A resposta do  Úlpio Netto tem um problema. Ao fazer `num = int(input("insira um numero"))`, se não for digitado um número, é lançado um `ValueError`, e como este erro não é capturado, o programa se encerra (em vez de mostrar a mensagem "Dado inválido", que é o que vc queria. A outra resposta mostra como tratar isso (com `try`/`except`). O `while` faria sentido se fosse para pedir pra digitar novamente, caso seja inválido, algo assim: https://ideone.com/ja11yd

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Existem duas formas de resolver essa situação, podemos criar um laço while que vai verificar o tipo do dado inserido

EX:

```
while(type(num) != int):
    num = int(input("insira um numero"))
```

Enquanto o tipo da variável num não é inteiro ele pede novamente a entrada do dado.

A outra forma é usando essa condição de `(type(num) != int) num elif`

Comment: boa! obrigada :)

Answer (score -1):

Se você está querendo que caso seja digitado no `input` uma String, um número que não seja inteiro ou algum caractere inválido, entre na condição `else`, desse jeito não é possível.

Você precisa de um tratamento de erro:

```
try:
  num = int(input('Digite um número: '))
  if num % 2 == 0:
     print('O valor é par')
  else:
     print('O valor é ímpar')
except ValueError:
    print('Dado inválido')
```

**Explicando:**
No estrutura `if/else`, você trata coisas que sejam uma negação da outra(o contrário da outra).

No **python** um caractere e um número não inteiro não são o contrário de `%2 == 0`. Eles na verdade, são um erro. Por isso você precisa usar a estrutura de tratamento de erro (`try, except`).

Além disso, para resolver essa questão, você não precisa usar `elif`, pois tudo que não for `%2 == 0`, entra em else.

Comment: obrigada!! tinha tentado com o try, mas devo ter feito algo errado, pois não estava funcionando. muito útil sua explicação